# Swift - last index of string

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to get the last charcter from a given string. I know there is at least 1 character in the string. But when I write the code I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
func lastCharacter (of string: String) -> Character {
    guard string != "" else { 
        return errorCharacter 
    }

    return string[string.endIndex]
}
```

Here is the error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this. What's wrong with just `str.charactes.last`?

Answer (score 4):

The `endIndex` of a thing is not a valid subscript of that thing. It is *one beyond* the last valid index.

The easiest way to get the last character of a string is to get the `suffix(1)` of the string or the `last` of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return string.last!
```

Hope that helps you!